# How to access other partitions from android-x86 on dual boot with ubuntu-16.04

Tags: mount, android-x86, dual-boot

I have **android-x86** along side **ubuntu-16.04** I have installed android in a 16GB partition in my harddrive. I was wondering if it is possible to access other partitions from android as it just shows nothing in the `files` app. It would be pointless because all my pictures videos or other files are in those others partitions. I am not an expert so please let me know if additional information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can!
If you are new on Linux, it could be a little tricky.
Open terminal (if you don't have, install one), type:

```
su
mkdir /storage/windows
ntfs-3g /dev/block/sdaX /storage/windows
```

where X is the partition that you want to mount.

Comment: Why is it "windows"?

Comment: For the terminal, Termux is probably the best choice now for Android.